# "docker-entrypoint.sh\": executable file not found in $PATH

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm a noob with Docker and I keep getting this error for pretty much whatever I place inside my Dockerfile, and I'd like to know how to fix it:

```
FROM node:12.18.2-alpine

COPY --chown=node:node . .

USER node

CMD [ "node", "server.js" ]
```

I've simplified my Dockerfile since I still get the same error anyways.

docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  sharpimg:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: sharpimg
    container_name: sharpcontainer
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: .env
    ports:
      - "80:3000"
    volumes:
      - .:/home/sharpimg/app
      - node_modules:/home/node/app/node_modules
    command: nodemon --ignore './dist/' server.js

volumes:
   node_modules:
```

Versions:

```
Ubuntu 20
Docker version 19.03.8
docker-compose version 1.26.2
```

Full error:

```
$ sudo docker-compose up --build; docker-compose logs
Removing sharpcontainer
Building sharpimg
Step 1/4 : FROM node:12.18.2-alpine
 ---> 057fa4cc38c2
Step 2/4 : COPY --chown=node:node . .
 ---> Using cache
 ---> ec6d6aaf78fe
Step 3/4 : USER node
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 7a11c49c015a
Step 4/4 : CMD [ "nodemon", "server.js" ]
 ---> Using cache
 ---> e695913b2d66
Successfully built e695913b2d66
Successfully tagged sharpimg:latest
Recreating 6bc5228b5b83_sharpcontainer ... error

ERROR: for 6bc5228b5b83_sharpcontainer  Cannot start service sharpimg: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"docker-entrypoint.sh\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown

ERROR: for sharpimg  Cannot start service sharpimg: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"docker-entrypoint.sh\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
Attaching to sharpcontainer, 6bc5228b5b83_sharpcontainer
```

I've upgraded docker and docker-compose and I don't even use a `docker-entrypoint.sh` file so I'm not really understanding this error. Please help

Comment: seems like you need to install `RUN npm i nodemon -g` nodemon globally

Comment: @Adiii yeah that isn't the issue because when I run it without `nodemon` and just use `node` I still get the same eror. :/ See updated Dockerfile where I replace `nodemon` with `node`

Comment: It has to do something with docker-compose I think.. but just guessing

Comment: yead one quick way to investiagte its not docker-compose issue `docker run -it --rm your_image` and see the response

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the issue , just try to remove `node_modules:/home/node/app/node_modules
    command: nodemon --ignore './dist/' server.js` these two line from the compose

Comment: @Adiii I removed those two lines from the compose.yml file I still get the same error. However, when I try `docker run -it --rm your_image` the app is running correctly

Answer (score 1):

The `docker-entrypoint.sh` is the entrypoint script for node docker image.
When you changed the user, maybe you lost the `$PATH` and therefore the script was not found.
Try to keep the same user, and if doesn't work, maybe when you copy, you override the script?
Please check here [how is the suggested usage of node image.](https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/master/README.md#how-to-use-this-image)